# Add a condition in Html.DropDownList within asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have used this snippet in my view

```
<SELECT  name="id_category">
             @for (int item = 0; item < list_cat.Count; item++){
                    if (@list_cat[item].Id_category == @Model.Id_category) {
                    <OPTION VALUE="@list_cat[item].Id_category" selected >@list_cat[item].CName</OPTION>}
                    else{
                    <OPTION VALUE="@list_cat[item].Id_category" >@list_cat[item].CName</OPTION>
                        }
                                               }
                  </SELECT>
```

then, i replaced it by

```
 @Html.DropDownList("id_category", new SelectList(list_cat,"Id_category","CName"))
```

But the condition of selection of the item is missing.

How can i replace it with `Html.DropDownList`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your DropDownList like below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id_category", new SelectList(list_cat, "Id_category", "CName", Model.Id_category))
```